# RadGrid sorting and dataset sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, telerik, radgrid

I have a rad grid which is bound to Datatable. when I modify some value in grid and want the same modification to be applied in data table as well, its not modifying the exact record I modify in Grid. The data table sorting and Rad grid sorting is not matching.

```
protected void CreateModifyOrder(DataSet dtCurrentGridSet, String orderNbr)
{  
    if (grdMain.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (GridDataItem item in grdMain.Items)//loops through each grid row
        {
            if ((item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                dtCurrentGridSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["OrderNumber"] = orderNbr;
                dtCurrentGridSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["OrderDesc"] = orderDesc;
                dtCurrentGridSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["OrderDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(orderDate);
            }
            else
            {
                dtCurrentGridSet.Tables[0].Rows[item.DataSetIndex].Delete();
                dtCurrentGridSet.AcceptChanges();
                i--;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    grdMain.DataSource = dtCurrentGridSet;              
    grdMain.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: There should be a member `grdMain.SelectedItem` - cast it to `DataRow` and modify stuff there

Comment: One more issue in this. This line is not reading grid data from all pages but reading only from current page -    foreach (GridDataItem item in grdMain.Items)

Comment: You should consider asking a new question, and not use the comment section.